# How to get combobox to pass correct value to table?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to pass a selected value from a combo box that is databound to a table with document ids.  I am trying to pass the selected value to another table.  When I execute my code I get System.data.datarow in the field instead of the value.  Also that value does not stay in the box.  The combo box in question is docRelComboBox... the other combo box functions properly but it is not databound.

Here is the code I use to pass the value:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string intType = interestTypeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string document = docRelComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string first = firstTextBox.Text;
            string mid = middleTextBox.Text;
            string last = lastTextBox.Text;
            string com = comNameTextBox.Text;
            string alias = aliasTextBox.Text;
            string intNotes = interestNotesTextBox.Text;

            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            var matchedIntNumber = (from c in db.GetTable<Interest>()
                                     where c.InterestsKey == Convert.ToInt32(interestsKeyTextBox.Text)
                                     select c).SingleOrDefault();

            matchedIntNumber.InterestType = intType;
            matchedIntNumber.DocRel = document;
            matchedIntNumber.First = first;
            matchedIntNumber.Middle = mid;
            matchedIntNumber.Last = last;
            matchedIntNumber.ComName = com;
            matchedIntNumber.Alias = alias;
            matchedIntNumber.InterestNotes = intNotes;

            db.SubmitChanges();

        }
```

My combo box Datasource is documentsBindingSource which is correct, Display Member is DocID which is correct, valuemember is DocID (not sure if that is correct) and not sure what to do with selected value.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docRelComboBox.SelectedValue` instead of `docRelComboBox.SelectedItem`.

Comment: @mssergeant wow that worked thank you so much!  Now I can publish this thing =).